# How to grep particular word next to the specific keyword?

Tags: scripts

file Content:

```
ST*810*1591754~BIG*20180826*00007201948*20180816*8708251***PR~CUR*SE*USD~N1*ST*RENT-A-CENTER #00842*ZZ*00842~N3*801 E. WM. CANNON~N4*AUSTIN*TX*78745*US~N1*BT*RENT-A-CENTER~N3*5501 HEADQUARTERS DR~N4*PLANO*TX*75024*USA~REF*ZA*1527~ITD*ZZ*3*0*20180826*0*20180925*30*000****Net 30 Days~DTM*011*20180826~FOB*PP*ZZ*AUSTIN, TX 78745~IT1*4*1*EA*273.00*QR*IN*100023757*VP*M84241~IT1*1*3*EA*90.66*QR*IN*100023415*VP*M91X42~IT1*2*1*EA*560.82*QR*IN*100022553*VP*3220217/66~TDS*110580~ISS*5*EA~SE*19*1591754~
```

Output:

```
filename,00007201948,8708251,1527
```

' * ' delimited file is the content. BIG is one of my keyword, "BIG*20180826*00007201948*20180816*8708251*" , I need a command to print 'filename,00007201948,8708251,1527', grep the keyword 'BIG' and Need to print the data between 2nd to 3rd asterisk and  4th asterisk to 5th asterisk. And "REF*ZA*1527~" 'ZA' is a another keyword to get the next characters between asterisk(*) to tilt (~).

Comment: what is your specific keyword? Could you also please edit your question and add code formatting. It's difficult to read ...

Comment: are the "words" that follow the keyword a standard format in anyway? standard length, all numbers, ect.

Comment: ' * ' delimited file is the content. 

BIG is one of my keyword, "BIG*20180826*00007201948*20180816*8708251*" , I need a command to print  '8708251'. 

grep the keyword  'BIG' and Need to print the data between 4th asterisk to 5th asterisk.

Comment: Assuming that the fields are the same in each line of the file, does the following give close to what you want for your actual files? `awk -F'*' '{printf"%s,%s,%s,%s\n",FILENAME,$5,$7,$30}' test.txt` produces `test.txt,00007201948,8708251,1527~ITD`. If that works except you just need the `~ITD` removed from all the lines, that's pretty easy. If so, what specifically needs to be removed? Anything nonnumeric on the end? `~ITD` exactly? `~` followed by something on the end?

Comment: there are multiple occurrences of the  'BIG' Keyword.. "awk -F'*' '{printf"%s,%s,%s,%s\n",FILENAME,$5,$7,$30}'" This worked for first iteration alone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the clarifications you have made in the comments. We need to know how we can know what to extract. Which field is the "filename"? Which field is the `8708251`?  How can we know what to search for?

Answer (score 1):

With awk: use `~` as the *record separator* and `*` as the *field separator*:

```
awk -F'*' -v RS='~' -v OFS=, '
    $1 == "BIG" {a = $3; b = $5} 
    $2 == "ZA"  {c = $3} 
    END {print FILENAME, a, b, c}
' file
```

---

Note that this is how awk sees the file:

```
$ awk -v RS='~' -F'*' '{print NR, NF, $0}' file
1 3 ST*810*1591754
2 8 BIG*20180826*00007201948*20180816*8708251***PR
3 3 CUR*SE*USD
4 5 N1*ST*RENT-A-CENTER #00842*ZZ*00842
5 2 N3*801 E. WM. CANNON
6 5 N4*AUSTIN*TX*78745*US
7 3 N1*BT*RENT-A-CENTER
8 2 N3*5501 HEADQUARTERS DR
9 5 N4*PLANO*TX*75024*USA
10 3 REF*ZA*1527
11 13 ITD*ZZ*3*0*20180826*0*20180925*30*000****Net 30 Days
12 3 DTM*011*20180826
13 4 FOB*PP*ZZ*AUSTIN, TX 78745
14 10 IT1*4*1*EA*273.00*QR*IN*100023757*VP*M84241
15 10 IT1*1*3*EA*90.66*QR*IN*100023415*VP*M91X42
16 10 IT1*2*1*EA*560.82*QR*IN*100022553*VP*3220217/66
17 2 TDS*110580
18 3 ISS*5*EA
19 3 SE*19*1591754
20 1
```

The 20th record contains 1 field which is the newline at the end of the file.

Comment: Glenn, this is working only for the first set of  segment. My file content is having more than 100 set of segments.

Comment: This requirement should appear in the text of the question, don't you think? Perhaps you should provide a better sample. How are the sets separated from each other?

Comment: All the sets will be on same pattern, only the data vary from segment.

Comment: Are they all on the same line, or what?

Comment: Yes, all of them on same line. 

I am expecting a command to look for the keyword 'BIG' and Need to print the data between 2nd to 3rd asterisk and 4th asterisk to 5th asterisk. And "REF*ZA*1527~" 'ZA' is a another keyword to get the next characters between asterisk(*) to tilt (~). 

Then again it  should look for the keyword 'BIG'  and 'ZA' again till the last letter. so, the second occurrence should be in second line.

Sample Output:
filename,00007201948,8708251,1527
filename,00007201949,8708290,1528
filename,00007201958,8708651,3094

Comment: If they are all on the same line, how do you separate them? Really, this is the third time I've had to ask you this. **PUT BETTER SAMPLE INPUT IN YOUR QUESTION**